# Can someone explain why this doesn't remove all values less than limit?

Tags: c++, remove-if

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int removeLessThan(std::vector<int>& v, int limit) {
  std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [limit](int a){return a < limit;});
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My output:

Vector after removing all values under 44: [ 28 43 40 42 8 24 12 25 31 13 36 30 28 35 37]

Desired output:

Vector after removing all values under 44: [ ]

So why does my code not remove any elements when it should remove everything?

Comment: -> `v.erase(std::remove_if(/*..*/), v.end())`.

Comment: or [`std::erase_if(v, pred);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) (C++20).

Answer (score 5):

> why does my code not remove any elements when it should remove everything?

Actually, [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) moves at beginning of the range all elements which don't satisfy predicate, AND returns iterator of the new end.

So usage is [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [limit](int a){return a < limit;}),
        v.end());
```

In c++20, it can be simplified thanks to [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2):

```
std::erase_if(v, [limit](int a){return a < limit;});
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of `std::remove`/`std::remove_if` functions are somewhat misleading in fact. They don't remove anything and should have named rather something like **shift_if**, because these functions just shift elements inside of the container and return past-the-end iterator for the new range of values. So you are supposed to *erase* these elements yourself:

```cpp
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [limit](int a){return a < limit;}), v.end());
```